# What is Homodyne BPSK?

Tags: digital-communications, modulation, bpsk

Could someone explain what Homodyne BPSK is? What is a difference between BPSK and Homodyne BPSK?

I have read about this type of modulation in researches in optic communication. I surprised how phase modulation can be used in optic/laser system.

Comment: Re: How phase modulation can be used in optical systems: Discussed in depth in the comments to your first question:

Comment: Do you know what "Homodyne" means? If not, why aren't you asking this first, before applying it to BPSK? (in fact, it's unusual to call a modulation "homodyne". You can call a *receiver* homodyne, and I suspect you read "homodyne BPSK receiver" and thought there was "Homodyne BPSK", where in reality there's only a "BPSK receiver that's a homodyne receiver". For a homodyne receiver, you typically need your modulation to be a *residual carrier* modulation, so that a BPSK modulation used in such a system might become an "offset BPSK" or a "residual carrier BPSK")

Comment: @MarcusMüller I have found this in a data sheet of an [optic terminal](https://www.tesat.de/images/tesat/products/LCT135_Data-Sheet.pdf).  here they performed a terminal with homodyne BPSk modulation

Comment: exactly, the *process* of modulation is homodyne. This is a bit confusing, because in English, "modulation" means "mixing", "changing the properties of a carrier" as well as "constellation".

Comment: @MarcusMüller It is not clear for me, if we cannot use phase modulation technique, how can we use homodyne BPSK receiver?

Comment: again, nobody says you cannot use phase modulation. You've been pointed at, and found, resources that do use PSK. Why do you still say "we cannot use phase modulation technique"? That's plain *wrong*.

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the space SE (where you also  post a similar question), the term "homodyne" often refers to a receiver architecture, as opposed to "heterodyne" as explained by [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homodyne_detection).

The use of TESAT of "homodyne BPSK modulation" is incorrect and misleading. If there were a modulation called "homodyne X", then there should be as well a modulation called "heterodyne X". But (I bet), you haven't been able to find any definition, in articles 'except those authored by engineers at TESAT) or in text books, of "homodyne BPSK", "homodyne QPSK", "heterodyne BPSK" ect.

We can guess, from the beginning of the article [Homodyne BPSK-based optical Inter-Satellite links](https://arc.aiaa.org/doi/abs/10.2514/6.2006-5460) what the authors (affiliated to TESAT) meant by "homodyne BPSK" (emphasis added by me).

> Homodyne BPSK is based on *coherent* detection. For that purpose, the signal is superimposed to a beam of a so-called local oscillator laser running on the *same frequency* as the signal's carrier. The optical phases of both signal and local oscillator need to be locked by a control loop ...

Those skilled in demodulations have immediately recognized the textbook description of a carrier recovery PLL (whether in RF or optical domains), with the use of term "superimposed" in place of "mixing", or mathematically speaking, multiplying two signals together. What is implied here is that this mixing is performed directly at the optical frequency. The outputs of this mixing, when the OL frequency is locked to the transmitted center frequency, are the I and Q components of the BPSK, or the I only when the phase offset is nullified.

Hence, the term "homodyne" applies to the receiver's synchronization function, part of the detection problem. The modulation and the demodulation functions remain those of a classical Binary Phase Offset Keying.

---

EDIT1: To address the 2nd part

> I surprised how phase modulation can be used in optic/laser system.

I am surprised that you are surprised. Here are some reading resources

- Wiki on [Electro-Optical Modular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electro-optic_modulator)

> An electro-optic modulator (EOM) is an optical device in which a signal-controlled element exhibiting an electro-optic effect is used to modulate a beam of light. The modulation may be imposed on the phase, frequency, amplitude, or polarization of the beam. Modulation bandwidths extending into the gigahertz range are possible with the use of laser-controlled modulators.

- [Intechopen](https://www.intechopen.com/chapters/70395)

> Optical phase-modulation technique is a very powerful tool used in a wide variety of high performance photonic systems. Fiber-optic sensors and gyroscopes, integrated-optics sensors, or high-performance photonic integrated circuits are some examples of photonic systems where the optical phase-modulation technique can be efficiently applied

---

EDIT2: Phase measurement at the optical receiver

This is achieved through [Interferometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interferometry). Extract from Wiki

> Interferometry makes use of the principle of superposition to combine waves in a way that will cause the result of their combination to have some meaningful property that is diagnostic of the original state of the waves. This works because when two waves with the same frequency combine, the resulting intensity pattern is determined by the phase difference between the two waves

Comment: i have read data sheets of "active" devices anf foud they used OOK or PM modualtions. I asked about why we cant use PSK modualtion in optic, the answer was photo diode detect power and no info about phase is saved.

Comment: @adil-kolenko, does PM means Phase Modulation?

Comment: pulse modulation

Comment: @adil-kolenko, I don't know who gave you the information that phase information is not possible in optical comms. I have added an Edit to debunk that. You should now have all the information to challenge that person's claim.

Comment: theoretically, we can use it.  if you have a look at the data sheets of LCT, you will not find any device with PSK modulation

Comment: @Adil.Kolenko you **yourself** link to documentation of manufacturers that offer PSK LCT devices. Multiple experts told you these devices exist. Can you stop claiming these devices don't exist? You're wasting everyone's time that way!

Comment: @Adil.Kolenko, a simple [Google](https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&client=ubuntu&q=BPSK+LCT) returns positive results. You should learn how to use search tool. If you don't understand why some manufacturers prefer to use OOK, or you don't understand the trade-offs between BPSK and OOK, you can ask such question on this SE.